# What is the use of PrintWriterPrinter in Android?

Tags: java, android, printwriter, println

During researches within Android's Developer Database, I stumbled upon PrintWriterPrinter (inside android.util):
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/PrintWriterPrinter.html

The source code of the PrintWriterPrinter class is shown below:

```
package android.util;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

/**
 * Implementation of a {@link android.util.Printer} that sends its output
 * to a {@link java.io.PrintWriter}.
 */
public class PrintWriterPrinter implements Printer {
    private final PrintWriter mPW;

    /**
     * Create a new Printer that sends to a PrintWriter object.
     * 
     * @param pw The PrintWriter where you would like output to go.
     */
    public PrintWriterPrinter(PrintWriter pw) {
        mPW = pw;
    }

    public void println(String x) {
        mPW.println(x);
    }
}
```

As you can see, it only has one single method: println(String x) which essentially applies println to the passed PrintWriter.
My question: Why would I use this useless PrintWriterPrinter if I could just manually call *println* on my PrintWriter object instead of creating a PrintWriterPrinter and then call *println* on that (which then calls *println* on a PrintWriter)?

Comment: printing String on console/

Comment: @Amy well actually not, it prints a string to a PrintWriter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is `implements Printer`.

When you learned Java programming, you learned about [Java interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html). A class declares that it implements an interface via the `implements` keyword; `PrintWriterPrinter implements Printer` indicates that `PrintWriterPrinter` implements the `Printer` interface.

If you look at the `Printer` interface in the JavaDocs, you will see that it defines that sole `println()` method. However, if you look carefully, you will see that the JavaDocs list four implementations of that interface: `LogPrinter`, `PrintStreamPrinter`, `PrintWriterPrinter`, and `StringBuilderPrinter`.

Through what is known as [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html), other code can work with an object known to implement the `Printer` interface — calling `println()` on that object — without knowing or caring which of these four implementations lies behind that object. Other developers could create yet other implementations of the `Printer` interface (e.g., one that stores the last 50 lines in an `ArrayList`), and the rest of the framework needing a `Printer` could use that custom implementation without issue.

Comment: alright.... I guess that means that next time I need to do more research than I did... thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly to hide some methods on the PrintWriter for the intended use, for instance flush/close methods?

Comment: That would make no sense... because I cannot output the contents of the PWP, I would have to reference the PW for that

Comment: Whether it makes sense or not, I guess depends on whether the Printer interface makes sense. It allows you to pass something to print while hiding/encapsulating/protecting some other methods of the object(s) implementing the Printer. For instance, the PrintWriter cannot be closed  through the Printer interface, perhaps before the creator of the PrintWriterPrinter intended.